# How to find the transformation between two IMU measurements?

Tags: quaternions, robotics, imu

I am looking at the Clubs Dataset https://clubs.github.io/ for some research into multiway registration of point clouds. I am initially trying to use the ICP registration method in a sequential order adding one point cloud at a time.

The dataset has the RGB parameters for the various poses of the object.

```
1525694104,-0.0913515162993169,-0.16815189159691318,0.4504956847817425,0.4591556084159897,-0.7817619820248951,-0.3682132612946675,0.20601769355692517
1525694157,-0.22510740390250225,-0.32514596548025265,0.45221561140129063,0.2388698281592328,-0.8750788198918591,-0.4081451880445991,0.10293936130543749
1525694174,-0.4179094161019803,-0.39403349319958664,0.4522321523188167,-0.004021371419719342,0.9070013543525104,0.4210736433584828,0.005455788205342825
```

The columns are namely

> filename, translation across 3 axes, quaternion for rotation.

I converted the images into point clouds and when I try to align the point clouds, I would need to have a good estimation of the transformation. Given the measurements at two points, how would I find out the transformation between those points. I would use that as my intiial estimate of my ICP registration algorithm.